# What should I verify when change current user's password?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working on a spring-mvc project which using spring-security to authenticate. I'm also using encrypt to encode password and store in database.

And now I'm trying with change password function. Usually we have `old password` and `new password`.

So I have some question.

1. User only can change their password after logged in. So is it necessary to verify `old password` again?
2. If we have to verify how can we do it in spring with an `old password` had been encode?

I'm using `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to encode password.

Comment: How did you encode the password? Normally it should be hashed so that you can compute the hash of the entered password and compare it with the old hash (that is stored in the database).

Comment: Please see my edit @HyperZ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `matches` method of `BCryptPasswordEncoder` is useful for this:

```
if (passwordEncoder.matches(changePasswordForm.getOldPassword(),
                                user.getPassword())) {
    // ok
} else {
    // wrong old password
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, **yes** you MUST check old pass again because session may be opened and another user can maliciously change the password causing troubles to both, admin and user.

Second, you not decript old pass (* see note), you encript user's old pass input and compare it with database. It's simply execute a login again. Same login process/method will do the work for you.

**NOTE** as Diego pointed:
To be precise: **your stored password should be NON decryptable.** Otherwise whoever gets a hold of the encrypted stuff can decrypt them, as you do.

Comment: To be precise: your stored password should be NON decryptable. Otherwise whoever gets a hold of the encrypted stuff can decrypt them, as you do.

Comment: When I try to encrypt current user's old pass by BCryptPasswordEncoder it's difference from what I have stored in database.

Comment: @user3422401 If that is true, how do you let users login then?

Comment: So do the same to verify the password